# Assigning the first character of a string literal to a char array assigns entire string literal

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am unsure how the following code works:

```
int p = 0;
char* arr = new char[20];
*((int*)&arr[p]) = *((unsigned int*)"ABCD");
```

Here are my observations:

```
arr[p]                   returns a char
&arr[p]                  gets the address of the char (char*)
(int*)&arr[p]            casts the char* to int*
*((int*)&arr[p])         dereferences the int* to int

"ABCD"                   is a char*
(unsigned int*)"ABCD"    casts the char* to unsigned int*
*(unsigned int*)"ABCD"   dereferences the unsigned int* to unsigned int
```

We then copy over the first character 'A' in "ABCD" (interpreting it as an unsigned int) to the first element in arr (interpreting it as an int). However upon inspection, not only is the first element in arr 'A' but the second, third and fourth is 'B', 'C' and 'D' respectively.

My question is, if we only copied over the first character 'A' in "ABCD" to the first element in arr, how did the other characters 'B', 'C' and 'D' get copied over also?

Thank you

Comment: Where did you copy only `'A'` ?  You just assigned whole string.

Comment: @inhwank: keep in mind, `sizeof(int)` is typically `4`, and `sizeof(char)` is typically `1`

Comment: Also keep in mind that this code causes undefined behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rule

Comment: @ameyCU I was under the impression "ABCD" is a char* to the first element of the string literal (i.e. 'A')

Comment: If you take the string "ABCDE" the code wouldn't work properly(don't tested).It works just because sizeof(int) = strlen(string) .

Comment: @inhwank  Well we all know that's not the case .It would be if you would have actually used a `char *` and stored string in it.

Comment: ""We then copy over the first character 'A' in "ABCD" (interpreting it as an unsigned int)"" - you didn't cast the first character to an `unsigned int`, rather, you cast a _pointer_ to the first character to a _pointer to_ `unsigned int` (which explains what you're seeing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your observations are perfectly correct, but you seem to missunderstand what the dereferenciation on the right hand side and the assignment mean.

You are not copying (and converting) one `char` to an `unsigned int`, but you effectively copy `sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes from one address to another.

This is one reason, why c-style cast are so dangerous (1): You are not casting a char to an unsigned int and assign it, you are casting a **pointer** to a char to a **pointer** to `unsigned int` and then dereference it. So, when dereferencing the right hand side, the compiler just assumes that the four bytes (`sizeof(unsigned int)`) starting at the given address comprise an `unsigned int` and does only a conversion from `unsigned int` to `int`.

What you apparently wanted to do is this:

```
*((int*)&arr[p]) = unsigned int("ABCD"[0]);
```

But, keep in mind that - as M.M pointed out - the left side is UB anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You write:

> We then copy over the first character 'A' in "ABCD" (interpreting it as an unsigned int) to the first element in arr (interpreting it as an int).

This assumption is wrong.

Because of the casts, `*((int*)&arr[p]) = *((unsigned int*)"ABCD");` copies an `unsigned int` whose size is 4 and therefore B,C and D are copied as well.

I hope you are aware that you wouldn't write code like that in real life.